# BindingList ListChanged event not firing until filled with data?

Tags: c#, events, data-binding, binding, datagridview

I'm writing code to eventually pull data from a remote database into a DataGridView using a databinding. I am currently creating the code to work with a CSV file and a BindingList as a test.

I want a display on my form that shows the last time the database was updated. I'm currently using the ListChanged event on my BindingList to update the "last database update" display.

The ListChanged event seems to only be firing if it's hooked up after the database is initially populated. Here's some code from my class that extends DataGridView:

```
BindingList<CsvTest> Data = new BindingList<CsvTest>;

public void InitGrid()
{
    // Data.ListChanged += Data_ListChanged;  // Event never fires if this is here!
    Data = CsvTest.ParseCsv("test.csv");
    Data.ListChanged += Data_ListChanged;     // Working when it's here!
    this.DataSource = Data; // DataGridView DataSource
}
```

I would like for my delay to update as the list is initially populated. Can anyone think of any reason why this isn't working?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: is `ParseCsv` returning a new `BindingList`?, if so that's most likely the reason, try clearing the Binding list and adding the items, the event will most likely work in that scenario.

Comment: That was the problem... Amateur Hour! Post a response and I'll mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
Data = CsvTest.ParseCsv("test.csv");
```

will overwrite the content of you `Data` variable. Any value that was set before (for example `Data.ListChanged`) will belong to the old `BindingList` object. And your new `BindingList` object does not have the value, until you set it.

If you would like to set the value before `ParseCsv`, you will have to clear the `BindingList` in `Data` and then add all items from `ParseCsv`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: If you read the comments, it will actually answer the question. I make an answer instead of a comment so @janderson can mark it as answered

Comment: @TobiasLiefke The OP had already left a comment suggesting sa_ddam213 post it as an answer more than a year ago. That's not going to happen. And there is no policy against posting comments of others as answers if they actually answer the question. The comment area is not where answers are supposed to be posted, the answer area is, and Phoenix_uy is right to fix the problem by trying to move the answer to the appropriate location. At best you can say that it would have been nice if this answer had been marked Community Wiki, but even then there is no requirement to do so.