# Winforms MVVM GridView DataBinding

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm, binding

I am trying to bind a GridView using a `BindingList<T>` in an MVVM pattern.

In my code, I bind the gridview as follows:

```
BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource(Context.MyList, null);
bindingSource.CurrentChanged += Context.BindingSourceCurrentItemChanged;
// NOTE: this part is to test if the event is fired...
Context.MyList.ListChanged += myList_ListChanged;
myGrid.DataSource = bindingSource;
```

I have an add button that calls a method in the Context as an `ICommand`:

```
Context.myCommand.Execute(null);
```

Finally, in the command itself (which is in the Context class), I do the following:

```
MyList.Add(new Item());
```

Pretty straight forward implementation... The `bindingSource.CurrentChanged` does fire properly, but I never enter the `myList_ListChanged` event.

If I stop on the launching of the `ICommand` and add several items, the `Context.MyList` count is indeed updated. Same occurs with if I use delete command...

Is there anything obvious I am missing here ???

Thanks in advance,
N.

**EDIT**
I realized that for the problem comes from the fact I have MyList as a property as follows:

```
BindingList<T> myList;
public BindingList<T> MyList {
    get {
      if (myList == null) { myList = new BindingList<T>();}
      return myList;
    }
}
```

I create the `BindingSource` in the form's constructor, whereas I have the following code called in the ViewModel **AFTER** the binding is made:

```
myList = new BindingList<T>
RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
```

I know this is WPF thinking, where this would update data bindings seamlessly.

As I understand this, `BindingSource` doesn't seem to listen to the changes of the datasource itself (i.e. the pointer to the object), as opposed to changes of its content.

Would anyone be kind enough to confirm this behavior?
Thanks!
N.

Comment: `Winforms MVVM` - there's no such thing. You're looking for WPF.

Comment: take it as "MVC" if you really want to...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966963/bindinglist-listchanged-event-not-firing-until-filled-with-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome the issue, simply set the binding to the datasource as follows:

```
myGrid.DataBindings.Clear(); // binding must be unique, make sure it is!    
myGrid.DataBindings.Add("DataSource", Context, "MyList");
```

Then, as long as there is a property change raised at the "Context" level, you'll be fine.